# Take In The Details

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the usage of the verb phrase "*take in*" [here](https://wau.org/archives/article/in_gods_hands/):

> Gazing about me, I ***took in*** the details of the people surrounding me in the courtyard of a Russian Orthodox church.

I checked this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/take-in) and none of the definitions for "*take in*" seems to fit the usage.  Could the example sentence be poorly written?

Comment: Try definition 5: "to take notice of something with your eyes"  In fact the example given matches your usage almost exactly: *He took in every detail of her appearance.*

Comment: yes, definition 5 equals the meaning of the sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sentence is using 'took in' in correct (if somewhat uncommon) manner. The dictionary you link lists this use as sense 5: 'to take notice of something with your eyes'.

This sense of 'took in' is basically synonymous with 'observed' - it suggests (to me, at least) a passive watching of a scene, rather than actively looking around it.